# Is there a shampoo that does not contain SLS or cocamidopropyl betaine?

Tags: dermatology, allergy, shampoo

If there is someone who is allergic to cocamidopropyl betaine and concerned about skin irritation from SLS (Sodium Lauryl Sulfate), is there a resource that shows shampoos without these ingredients?

Comment: I have edited your question to make it more applicable to the site, and not just a "recommend me" type question. If you do not agree with the edits, please respond and I will roll them back (Although it may make your question likely to be closed).

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma - See my comment above. Rather than always immediately voting to close, see if there is a way to salvage the question and bring it more into alignment with where the site is and where we want it to be.

Comment: @JohnP Thank you for taking the time to edit the question. I would be very surprised (in a positive way) if such a resource exist, I didn’t even consider that to be an option. But in the end, we’re all here to learn.

Comment: https://www.aad.org/media/news-releases/getting-past-the-hype-dermatologist-untangles-common-hair-care-misconceptions

Comment: The challenge is that the major organizations don't usually list specific product lists (risk of advertising) so cosmo or a similar source might be the only one.  And it's just an item on an ingredients list.